# Lists elements are overwritten while adding a list to a list

Tags: .net, vb.net, list

I have the following code:

```
Dim innerList As New List(Of String)
Dim outerList As New List(Of List(Of String))

For Each ds As datasource In datasources

    selectedIdentifier = ds.identifier

    Dim columnInfos As New List(Of Columns)
    columnInfos = client.getColumns(token, selectedIdentifier)

    For Each colInfo As Columns In columnInfos
        innerList.Add(colInfo.code)
    Next

    outerList.Add(innerList)
    innerList.Clear()
Next
```

What I try to do is the following thing. I have different datasources. All of these datasources have different columnnames (=`.code`) while the number of columns is different too. I want to store the columnnames of one datasource in a list (`innerlist`) and store all these lists in another list (outerList).

What I do not understand is: Setting a stopper at line: `outerList.Add(innerList)` the list holds the right data for the current datasource in the *first iteration*. Coming to the *second iteration* the list holds the data of the second datasource twice (apparentely the data of the first dataset is overwritten with the data of the first dataset). So the data of

```
outerlist (i) j and outerlist (i+1) j
```

are the same and I just do not see why this is happening?

Comment: Please don't use the C# tag in questions that aren't about C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a single list for `innerList`, and adding that reference to `outerList` on each iteration... so your `outerList` ends up containing lots of references to the same list, which ends up empty because you clear it. You should create a new list on each iteration - I'd declare `innerList` in the loop as well:

```
Dim outerList As New List(Of List(Of String))

For Each ds As datasource In datasources
    Dim innerList As New List(Of String)
```

... and remove the call to `Clear()` at the end, as otherwise you'll end up with lots of references to *different* empty lists.

Note that all of this would be a lot simpler using LINQ - you could do the whole thing in a more declarative way in about 5 lines of code. I'd show those lines, but as query syntax in VB is somewhat different to C#, I would probably get it wrong - you should look into LINQ though...

Answer (score 1):

`innerList` always references the same list *instance*, so you're clearing it then adding another *reference* to the "outer" list.  Put in other words, `outerlist (i)` and `outerlist (i+1)` *are the same list*.

You could change

```
innerList.Clear()
```

to

```
innerList = New List(Of String)
```

to create a NEW list each time, or declare the variable within the loop:

```
Dim outerList As New List(Of List(Of String))

For Each ds As datasource In datasources

    Dim innerList As New List(Of String)

    selectedIdentifier = ds.identifier

    Dim columnInfos As New List(Of Columns)
    columnInfos = client.getColumns(token, selectedIdentifier)

    For Each colInfo As Columns In columnInfos
        innerList.Add(colInfo.code)
    Next

    outerList.Add(innerList)
Next
```

Note that you can also use [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384667.aspx) to do this in a single query, but I wanted to illustrate the reason you're seeing those results.